# InternalError: Cannot convert Array to number[][] - Error in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker, converters

due to it tickets [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754071/export-data-with-relations-in-excel/57773076#57773076) I now have the problem "InternalError: Cannot convert Array to number[][]" .

I'm telling you that setValues in line 81 causes problems. But I can't quite understand why.

Maybe someone can help me find the error/problem.

```
 function baueSoftwareRow(Software, UnternehmenName) {
var UnternehmenVertragsgegenstand = Software.Vertragsgegenstand ;
var UnternehmenAnsprechpartnerD =Software.AnSP_Lieferant;
var UnternehmenVertragseigner =Software.Vetragseigner_Vertantwortlicher ;
/*var UnternehmenAnsprechpartnerNG =Software.Ansprechpartner || "";
var UnternehmenVertraege =Software.Vertraege || "";
var UnternehmenApp =Software.App || "";
var UnternehmenAVV =Software.AVV || "";
var UnternehmenNDA =Software.NDA || "";
var UnternehmenProjekt =Software.letztes_Projekt || "";
var UnternehmenKreditor =Software.Kreditor || "";
var UnternehmenKdnr =Software.KDNR || "";
var UnternehmenKlasse =Software.Klasse1 || "";
var UnternehmenISO270001 =Software.ISO270001 || "";
var UnternehmenDSGVO =Software.DSGVO_Taetigkeit || "";
var UnternehmenText_AVV1 =Software.Text_AVV_Taetigkeit || "";
var UnternehmenText_AVV2 =Software.Text_AVV_Bewertung || "";*/
var newRow = [UnternehmenName, UnternehmenVertragsgegenstand, UnternehmenAnsprechpartnerD, UnternehmenVertragseigner,/* UnternehmenAnsprechpartnerNG, UnternehmenVertraege, UnternehmenApp, UnternehmenAVV, UnternehmenNDA, UnternehmenProjekt,UnternehmenKreditor, UnternehmenKdnr, UnternehmenKlasse, UnternehmenISO270001, UnternehmenDSGVO, UnternehmenText_AVV1, UnternehmenText_AVV2*/ ]; //save Unternehmensdaten in a row
return newRow;
```

}

```
function sammelSoftwareRows(allSoftware, UnternehmenName ) {
var data = [];
for (var j= 0; j< allSoftware.length; j++) {
      var newSoftWareRow = baueSoftwareRow(allSoftware[j], UnternehmenName);
      data.push(newSoftWareRow); //*
    }
return data;
```

}

function baueUnternehmen(Unternehmen) {
    var UnternehmenName =Unternehmen.Hersteller;

```
var allSoftware = Unternehmen.Software; //*

var gesammelteSoftwareDiesesUnternehmens = sammelSoftwareRows(allSoftware, UnternehmenName);

    return gesammelteSoftwareDiesesUnternehmens;
```

}

```
//define function to do the data export 
function ExportDaten(SoftwareUnternehmen) {
  //create sheet to populate data
  var fileName = new Date()+"Dienstleisterverzeichnis "; //file name
  var newExport = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName); // create new spreadsheet
  var header = ["Name", "Vertragsgegenstand", "Ansprechpartner Dienstleister","Vertragseigner bzw. Verantwortlicher ",/*"Ansprechpartner ","Verträge","App","AVV","NDA","letztes Projekt bzw. letzter Kontakt","Kreditor#","Kdnr beim Lieferanten","Klasse","ISO270001?","DSGVO Tätigkeit nach Verfahrensverzeichnis","Text AVV: Tätigkeit","Text AVV: Bewertung"*/]; //define header
  newExport.appendRow(header); // append header to spreadsheet
  var data = []; //*

  //get all Unternehmen records
  var ds = app.models.Unternehmen.newQuery();
  ds.prefetch.Software._add(); //*
  var allUnternehmen = ds.run();
   // Sets a rollback point and starts a new transaction.
  //app.transaction.cloudSql.start();

   // Locks all records that are read in the transaction until the end of the transaction.
 // app.transaction.cloudSql.setLockOnRead(app.transaction.cloudSql.lockOnRead.UPDATE);

  for(var i=0; i< allUnternehmen.length; i++) {
    //get each student data
    var Unternehmen = allUnternehmen[i];

  //  console.log(Unternehmen.Hersteller);

    if (Unternehmen.Hersteller !== ""){
    var Zeilen = baueUnternehmen(Unternehmen);

    for(var Zeile in Zeilen){
    //  console.log(Zeile);
      data.push(Zeile);
    }

    }

  //console.log("Export fertig");
}
  console.log("Laenge: " + data.length);
  console.log("Laenge: " + header.length);
  console.log(data);
newExport.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,data.length+1,header.length).setValues(data); //*  HIER IST DER FEHLER BEI setValues
console.log("Export fertig");
```

}

[Errormessage in log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP45z.jpg)
many thanks in advance

Comment: The only problem I'm seeing at the moment is data.length+1 in `.getRange(2,1,data.length+1,header.length)` which likely causes the getRange dimension to be larger than the setValues dimension. They need to be equal to each other so the +1 I think throws that off.

Comment: Thank you very much, I deleted the +1 from my code. Unfortunately nothing has changed.  The error is indicated in the line: newExport.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,data.length,header.length).setValues(data); //*

Comment: Hm, next item to maybe look at is your data array. Your log of data shows this as being one dimensional in the format of [], but it should be 2 dimensional like [[],[],[]]. I’m not sure if this happens because your header and data constructor include */text,text,etc/* in index position 4, but it could be part of the problem although the length of your header log still reflects 4 if that basically means to skip the rest of the header and data array.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I found the error. It was a typo in a field name and the for instruction had to be adjusted. 

          var lines = baueSoftware(Software);
        
          for (var idx = 0; idx < lines.length; idx++){
            Line = lines[idx];
            var index = data.push([]);
            data[index-1] = line;

          }